# JQgrid cell tooltipl as Html

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

I am displaying a column in Jqgrid with divs and html tag, for example it is

```
<div><a> Click here to order tjos service.</a></br> Note: The service is disabled</div>.
```

When I hover my pointer to the cell it doesn't display the content properly which means it doesn't show the link then a new line it shows the note as a tooltip

Anybody knows how to solve this please?

Thanks,
Alaa

Answer (score 0):

You may use tooltip plugin, like [JQuery Tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) or some other.

Just create the tooltips in your formatter for this cell.